# Office365/Sharepoint 2013 Authentication

Tags: sharepoint-2013, saml, office365

I am trying to authenticate to our sharepoint server https://company.sharepoint.com but i am getting Authentication Failure No URL.

I Construct a SOAP/SAML message

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s='http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope' xmlns:a='http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing' xmlns:u='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd'> <s:Header> <a:Action s:mustUnderstand='1'>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/RST/Issue</a:Action> <a:ReplyTo> <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address> </a:ReplyTo> <a:To s:mustUnderstand='1'>https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf</a:To> <o:Security s:mustUnderstand='1' xmlns:o='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd'> <o:UsernameToken> <o:Username>%@</o:Username> <o:Password>%@</o:Password> </o:UsernameToken> </o:Security> </s:Header> <s:Body> <t:RequestSecurityToken xmlns:t='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust'> <wsp:AppliesTo xmlns:wsp='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy'> <a:EndpointReference> <a:Address>%@</a:Address> </a:EndpointReference> </wsp:AppliesTo> <t:KeyType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/NoProofKey</t:KeyType> <t:RequestType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/Issue</t:RequestType> <t:TokenType>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion</t:TokenType> </t:RequestSecurityToken> </s:Body> </s:Envelope>
```

i provide the username = "someuser@company.xx", password = "123456" and EndpointReference = "https://company.sharepoint.com"

then i send a request to "https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf" to get the token. what am i missing?